# select query based on different criteria

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have a table that looks like the one below. I want to query the table based on two criterias.
If the id has a count that is negative I want to get the maximum results based on that id . Also if an id only has positive numbers than I want to get the min based on that id.

```
id         tcount
---        ------
 1           -5
 1           -10
 1            5
 2           20
 2           30
 3           -40
 3           -50
```

So the results I would want to get is this

```
id         tcount
--         -----
 1           -5
 2           20
 3          -40
```

My query would look something like this and I would need to add more logic to it

```
SELECT id, max(count) as tcount
FROM atable
WHERE count < 0
GROUP by id
```

Comment: Ah! so you want the closer-to-zero number! (took me a while to understand that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if this works. To get the minimum/maximum negative and the minimum/maximum positive, `case ... end` can help you:

```
select id
     , min(case when tcount < 0 then tcount end) -- Minimum negative
     , max(case when tcount < 0 then tcount end) -- Maximum negative
     , min(case when tcount >= 0 then tcount end) -- Minimum non-negative
     , max(case when tcount >= 0 then tcount end) -- Maximum non-negative
     , min(tcount)
     , max(tcount)
from atable
group by id;
```

---

After reading again your question (took me two or three readings), I figured out that you want the number that is closer to zero for each group. So:

```
select id
     , min(abs(tcount)) * if(min(tcount) = min(abs(tcount)), 1, -1)
from atable
group by id;
```

**The explanation:**

`min(abs(tcount))` wil get the minimum of the absolute value of `tcount` (that is, the one that's closest to zero). All that remains is to get the proper sign for the number, and that's what that `if()` is for: If the minimum of the absolute value of the number is equal to the minimum of the number, then the number is positive (because that only can happen if `min(tcount)` is greater than zero, or equal to zero), in other case, the number is negative.

Comment: I am getting like 6 different columns. Is it possible just to get one?